# AWS Glue Dynamic frame writes with nullable field schema

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am reading avro with AWS glue, doing some ETL and rewriting avro.
The problem I have is before and after avro's don't have the same schema

```
root
|-- visit_id: int
|-- visit_date: int
|-- visit_date_timestamp: long
```

This is before and after and after it looks like this :

```
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "visit_id",
    "type" : [ "int", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "visit_date",
    "type" : [ "int", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "visit_date_timestamp",
    "type" : [ "long", "null" ]
}]
```

I am not sure how the type null is being added to the avro schema.